# Android ImageButton to navigate through activities

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I tried using ImageButton as a regular button to navigate from activity to activity. I have this activity containing 6 imagebuttons and I wish to have thee user go to their appropriate activity on click on any of the image buttons. This however, does not work. Can anyone guide me as to how to accomplish this?

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/book_shelf"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="WELCOME"
        android:textSize="40dip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:text="Autoplay" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:text="Read by self" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clown_icon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:src="@drawable/nurse_icon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton03"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:src="@drawable/police_w_icon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton02"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageButton01"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageButton03"
        android:src="@drawable/m_girl_icon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton04"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageButton02"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageButton05"
        android:src="@drawable/firefighter_icon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton05"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageButton03"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:src="@drawable/chef_w_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what my .java file looks like:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;


public class GirlMenuActivity extends Activity {
    ImageButton imagebtn1;
    ImageButton imagebtn2;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_girl);
        
        addListenerOnButton();
    }
    
    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        imagebtn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
        imagebtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
 
                Intent intent = new Intent
                        (getApplicationContext(), PracticeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see only one imagebutton has been implemented yet. It doesn't work.

Comment: do you get any errors? paste the logcat if yes.

Comment: You have `android:id="@+id/imageButton1"` and ` android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"`on two different elements - are you sure you're clicking the right one?

Comment: @Santhosh  There was no error in the logcat. Found my error. It was a linker problem. I was linking to the wrong activity.Thank you. :-)

Comment: @Montycarlo It wasn't about the imageButton id. Thanks for the quick reponse you two. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz check your XML page image button id and give it the different id..and then put your intent code ...and define also ur second class and give its to the manifest.xml

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, second.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_girl);

         imagebtn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        imagebtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent
                        (GirlMenuActivity.this, PracticeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent); 
            }
        });
    }


}
```

**P.S**:*Dont forget to add your `PracticeActivity` in your manifest file.*
Importantly check your other activity. If there is some thing which causes runtime error in `oncreate` then also it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

**try this code.hope it helps..**

```
imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent
                    (MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i); 
        }
    });
}
```

*then use same for another image buttons...*